# $\sigma$-algebra generated by a function

Tags: measure-theory

How can I show the following:

Consider the function $X:\Omega \rightarrow \Psi$. Show that $\sigma(X)=\{X^{-1}(A):A\in \mathcal{G}\}$.

What I have so far:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ and $(\Psi, \mathcal{G})$ be two measurable spaces. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Psi$ such that for all $A\in\mathcal{G}$, $X^{-1}(A)=\{\omega:X(\omega)\in A \}$. Thus, all elements of $\mathcal{G}$ are measurable to $\mathcal{A}$.

I need help in trying to show that $X^{-1}(\mathcal{G})=\{X^{-1}(A):A\in\mathcal{G}\}$ an relate that result to $\sigma(X)$

Comment: What is your definition of $\sigma(X)$?

Comment: @mark its the sigma algebra generated by the function $X:\Omega \rightarrow \Psi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection $\mathcal{F}=\{X^{-1}(A): A\in\mathcal{G}\}$ is a sigma algebra on $\Omega$, this is easy to prove.

$\Omega=X^{-1}(\Psi)$, so $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$.

If $B\in\mathcal{F}$ then there is some $A\in\mathcal{G}$ such that $X^{-1}(A)=B$. Then $\Omega\setminus B=X^{-1}(\Psi\setminus A)$ and hence $\Omega\setminus B\in\mathcal{F}$.

Finally, if $(B_n)$ is a sequence of sets in $\mathcal{F}$ then for each $n$ there is some $A_n\in\mathcal{G}$ such that $X^{-1}(A_n)=B_n$. Then $\cup_{n=1}^\infty B_n=X^{-1}(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$. So the union is also in $\mathcal{F}$.

So this is a Sigma Algebra, and $X$ is measurable with respect to it, as for each $A\in\mathcal{G}$ we have $X^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{F}$ by definition. Hence it contains $\sigma(X)$. On the other hand, let $B\in\mathcal{F}$. Then $B=X^{-1}(A)$ for some $A\in\mathcal{G}$. Since $X$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$ we must have $B\in\sigma(X)$. So $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\sigma(X)$ as well. So they are equal.

Comment: I was just wondering, how did you come up with $\mathcal{F}$? did you just assum this existed? Because I'm trying to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is in fact $X^{-1}(\mathcal{G})$

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You have a function $X$ and a sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}$ on $\Psi$, so the collection $\{X^{-1}(A): A\in\mathcal{G}\}$ is well defined. I called this collection $\mathcal{F}$. This is a sigma algebra on $\Omega$ and as I wrote in the answer it is actually equal to $\sigma(X)$, the smallest sigma algebra with respect to which $X$ is measurable.